# Connection retry strategy?

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are they any REPs or other documentation describing retry strategies for topics and services?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40967/connection-retry-strategy?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there are generic connection retries implemented at the moment.  There was some logic to do so, but it's only experimental.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-10-10**:
Thanks, Tully. I think maybe we can roll this into the ROS 2.0 SIG then. Or at least explicitly leave it out :)